# Refresh accesstoken without user credentials?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

currently I'm developing a gem (in ruby), which needs to access files in google drive. The whole authorization is done by OAuth2.0. Therefore I provide the client_id and client_secret in order to get an access token along with a refresh token. I store both in a database to access them anytime in the future. After 3600 seconds the access token is expired and I need to refresh it using the refresh token. Here comes the tricky part.

Can I get a new access token with a refresh token only? I'm refering to platforms like nimble. I registered once and have access to my files. But I still have access to my files on the next day, which means that they refreshed the access token somehow. Do they store my id and secret or what is the magic behind this? Or do they use SSO? And if so how can I get an access token from SSO?

Thanks for any advices.

Best regards

P.S.: I don't want to store the client id and secret, since these is sensible information, which I don't want to get stolen. Also encrypting it is not an option (so far).

Comment: No, you can't. client ID and Secret are necessary. They refresh token with their own id and secret.

Comment: I think I have an understanding problem here. They provide their ID and secret? I always thought that the user who wants to login via google has to provide his ID and secret?

Comment: I think you misunderstand. Client Id and child secret are credential of client, not user.

Comment: You're right. I always thought a user has to provide the client id and secret. This makes so much thinks way easier. Thank you for clearing that up.